# Alter table on global temporary table (preserve to delete)

Tags: database, oracle, temp-tables, alter-table

Is it possible to change a global temporary table in Oracle from PRESERVE ROWS to DELETE ROWS?

I have tried the following command and I get a syntax error. If it is possible, what is the correct syntax?

```
ALTER TABLE BLOCKING_RESULTS ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
```

> SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
>   01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. [The valid syntax is documented](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm), and doesn't include the ability to change this. Not being able to change this isn't listed explicitly as [one of the restrictions for GTTs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53302), but that only refers to things that are allowed for other types of table.

You'll have to drop and recreate the table with the new `on commit` clause.

Tom Kyte made a succinct comment on this [way back in 2003](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1086033238621#12163248747042).

(I'd *speculate* that it might be related to the statement that [table locks are not acquired on temporary tables.](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53524); though how it lets you add columns without that being an issue is interesting. Altering the preservation while sessions have data in the GTT might have odd side-effects anyway...)

Comment: Thank you. Changing to use a differently named table and later dropping the other when it's no longer in use will be a workable option for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to this example/article in step 7:

-You cannot alter a temporary table to change its data duration.

-You must drop and create it agin.

http://oracle-plsql-tech.blogspot.com.tr/2013/03/temporary-tables.html

If your case is same.

Answer (score -1):

syntax you have used is wrong. Try PL/SQL alter table syntax.